# Why does Xlim and Ylim not work as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why does the xlim and ylim not work as expected? It should show y-lim from 1-4 and xlim from 1-3. This is not the case. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Paste your code as text instead of image.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using NumPy's `loadtxt` to read the data into two separate arrays as shown in the following complete answer. Also, you should try to set the limits *after* plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.loadtxt('....\test.txt', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(1, 4)
plt.xlim(1, 3)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you plot seem to be text data. Try converting data into numbers. For example

```py
x = [float(row.split(' ')[0]) for row in data]
y = [float(row.split(' ')[1]) for row in data]
```

You can use `int` instead of `float` if input data are integers.

Comment: This is correct; if you plot a list of strings they are treated as "categories" instead of numbers.... https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html